# how to load multi textured object in jpct-ae

Tags: android, 3d, opengl-es-2.0, jpct

Right now I can load 3D model with single texture file using jpct-ae successfully.

```
cube = loadModel(getAssets().open("cube.3ds"), 1);
TextureManager.getInstance().addTexture("texture.png", new Texture(getAssets().open("texture.png")));

cube.build();
world.addObject(cube);
```

But now I have to load complex 3D model like car or house which contains multiple texture files. 3D model and texture is being downloaded from server so I cant define textures. 
How can I load 3d model with multiple textures is jpct-ae ??

Answer (score 1):

The basics are described here: [Loading models in jPCT(-AE)](http://www.jpct.net/wiki/index.php/Loading_models)

If you can't load the textures before the model, you can load the model first, let the loader assign some placeholder textures with the correct names and then load the textures and do some replaceTexture()-calls in the TextureManager to replace the placeholders with the correct textures.

Comment: thanx, it looks good idea. But my problem is when i download 3d model from server as zip file and store it on SD card. even if i load .obj model i will have to search through directory for all the possible jpegs or texture files to load as textures manually. so for now I am planning to use only the baked texture models so that i can have only one texture file , one material file and one obj file. this method seems more generic.